# Current 'most comprehensive' whole genome alignment resource for human?

Tags: ensembl, multiple-sequence-alignment, pangenome, whole-genome, ancient-dna

I found the human genome alignment sets here:
https://www.ensembl.org/info/genome/compara/multiple_genome_alignments.html

but they doesn't include, for example, ancient human genomes, e.g. those here:
https://reich.hms.harvard.edu/allen-ancient-dna-resource-aadr-downloadable-genotypes-present-day-and-ancient-dna-data

or, for example, any of the other 'pan genome' whole genome alignments here:
https://humanpangenome.org/

However, those latter two resources don't include whole genome alignments...

About 10 years ago I remember reading a paper that used 'lots' of genomes to uncover novel features using different patterns of conservation, demonstrating the power of the approach.

Have I missed a new, more up to date, whole genome alignment resource?

Many thanks,

Comment: This seems like it might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Can you please provide more context to your question and explain what you want to do with this resource? You're asking for a fairly large dataset, and there's probably a better way to do what you want without downloading all that data.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious thing missing from your list is the [telomere-to-telomere genome assemblies](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.abj6987) that have been coming out in the last couple years.

Assembly link [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjVuJqem5-CAxV1IDQIHU2mASIQFnoECCQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov%2Fassembly%2F11828891&usg=AOvVaw1Q8aP_L5RFstLQ0JtKVX6M&opi=89978449).

There are now a [few others as well](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41422-023-00849-5) that are similar.

It's been demonstrated that [this T2T assembly improves mapping rates](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9336181/), in some cases pretty dramatically.

I am not sure entirely what you want from whole genome alignments, but UCSC if not others [has incorporated the T2T assembly](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?db=hub_2395475_t2t-chm13-v1.0&lastVirtModeType=default&lastVirtModeExtraState=&virtModeType=default&virtMode=0&nonVirtPosition=&position=chr22%3A3977324%2D3977530&hgsid=1749469962_FUCnGU4vZLseVNNvfdKfFDr4aeOU). [Here is a related commentary](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-022-02735-6) (which I haven't read in any detail).